# Sanding off a MacBook's sharp edges

Tags: macbook-pro

The **edges** of both the MacBook Pro (aluminum case) and the MacBook (polycarbonate) are **exceedingly sharp**. Depending on my typing position, they dig in my wrists, an unpleasant and painful experience. Can you suggest a solution?

**Sanding is one option.** Did you perhaps sand-off the edges by using fine-sanding paper made for wood? Could you post an image of the result? It's understood it will not be as pretty afterwards, but being plain ugly is not an option either.

**Guards are another idea.** People sometime use guards on furniture with sharp features to save their kids when bumping into them. Can you think of a similar product (off-the-shelf or homemade) for the edges of a MacBook?

**Addendum**

Looking back at this old question years later I'm puzzled at the critiques of ergonomics. It's a laptop (FHS). You can switch it on anywhere and start typing. It may be the least ergonomic desk and typing positions ever. Coffee shops, for one, do not appear to particularly choose heights for tables with an eye to typing positions, understandably.

Whether polycarbonate or aluminum, the hard edge is painful on bare skin. The simplest solution (maybe this should technically be an answer, albeit a cheeky one) is to wear long sleeves. (If it's just too warm, ) The second-simplest solution is to carry a handkerchief along with the laptop and fold it to protect your skin. Either mimics the suggested glue-on solutions, but avoids ruining the clinically clean closure of a Macbook's screen.

Apple, if You're reading this, chamfer the (expletive) sharp front edges.

Comment: Added clarification.

Comment: I'm really worried about what sort of a typing position you're finding yourself using, if it brings your wrists into contact with the laptop edges. Nerve damage takes a lot longer to heal than skin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a youtube tutorial by a very brave person on how to file the edge off a MacBook Pro: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnGAlf1hjs4

More information is available here: http://onemansblog.com/2010/03/11/video-rant-taking-the-sharp-edge-off-the-macbook-pro/

Comment: Chamfering seems to be the right idea. A swiss-army knife solved the problem on the polycarbonate. As the video suggests, the metal is trickier. Either way some rounding, even with just a nearly imperceptible 0.5mm radius, would have been nice, especially if made by the manufacturer.

Comment: Would this void the warranty of the device?

Answer (score 4):

I posted this DIY solution to the Apple Discussions thread [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/184Pw.jpg) as well with a bit more "story line" as this isn't the place for that.

I created a vinyl wrap for the front edge with some sort of "padding" under just the corner! This is just a prototype and I intend to have my wife use her Cameo to cut a custom design for the vinyl wraps.

[image: Prototype] 
Here you can see that the vinyl is very thin and adds almost no thickness to the wrist area:
[image: Razor thin]
You can see the slight padding I have under the vinyl that just wraps the edge. For this "prototype" I just cut about a 1/4 inch strip of a paper towel. I used a "towel" type paper towel, not that harsh rough stuff. I had Viva brand on hand:
[image: Padding]
It's not impacting closing the MacBook at all as you can see here:
[image: Closed Tight]
I've used this for 2 days now working for approx 12 hours each day and I have no more harsh edge lines on my wrist. And she happened to have some scrap black vinyl that happens to match the keyboard perfectly. Looks pretty sweet. Of course I could find a brushed or just aluminum color so they would virtually be unnoticable.

Also, these are completely removeable without leaving any residue. If there is any left, it's very minor and removed by just slight rubbing of the residue. This is the same vinyl used for signs or crafts.

I may have my wife cut these on her Cameo with the theme of the OS releases. Lion (would have been) lion paws, Mavericks will be waves and Yosemite will be silhouettes of El Capitan and maybe Sentinel Rock. But who knows, maybe they will be flames or something else fun. We'll see.

Comment: Cool stuff! What type of adhesive are you using though?

Comment: They vinyl sheets already have an adhesive backing (self adhesive). The adhesive is strong enough to keep it on, but it's removable and comes off clean. It's a water based adhesive. I've put a few on and taken them off testing different padding materials and thicknesses for the edges.

Comment: The exact vinyl I'm using is [Oracal 631 Exibition](http://www.orafol.com/gp/americas/en/products/search-result-gpam-product-details/items/oracal-631-exhibition-cal). I think it was rebranded for [Cricut Vinyl](http://us.cricut.com/shopping/products-Vinyl-265.aspx) though (per my wife since she bought it through them she thinks). The original brand is printed all over the back though ;) Here is a bunch of different colors for it on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/rolls-Adhesive-Backed-Vinyl-Cutters/dp/B00AV8V3RK/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1402672105&sr=8-2&keywords=oracal)

Comment: But any self adhesive vinyl will work as long as it's safe for signs, crafts or walls (like for those vinyl sayings people put in their houses over beds, kids walls and the family rooms that are all the rage with the wives these days :) )

Comment: awesome! thanks for all the info. may try this myself before you patent it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternatives that you could consider:

1. Silicone case that wraps around to the keyboard - see this [macrumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=359491). Note: it's a bit dated (2007), so not sure if they still sell these types of ccases/covers anymore.
2. Guard strip - example from Amazon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HJLKIK). Product description indicates that the main purpose is to address the issue of sharp edges for the MBP. Something like that probably fits the bill perfectly.
3. Wrist rest (foam/leather) - example from Amazon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032Z8IJA). The rest may be able to put enough distance between your wrists and the edge.

**Caveat**: I don't have any problem with the edge, so I've never used any of these products. But one of these might address your comfort without necessitating the filing down of your MBP's edge, which would probably hurt its resale value.

Comment: The guard strip looks perfect if the laptop were to stay as a desktop machine, but then many people likely hook up a full-size monitor and the magic this and that. It's not clear whether the guard strip would survive putting the macbook frequently in a bag.

Answer (score 2):

A dremel type grinder would work for both. You'd want to mask off the case so you know when you're chewing too far into the top case. A guide or jig to hold the grinding wheel stationary would be better since you'd be less likely to go too far into the battery for example on the Polycarbonite model.

If you are dead set against changing your ergonomics so your wrists never know whether the edge is sharp or beveled, I would get help from someone in a machine shop that has experience with grinding. They will have practiced on many other items and likely have far better technique. The tools to both cut and [polish](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Manufacturing/Industry/Product-Catalog/Abrasives/3M-Finishing-Systems/) polycarbonate and aluminum are different, but knowing how to clamp down the mac and use a metal file properly would come in handy - especially if the shop has the tools and clamps needed and you only have to supply the patient and perhaps the finishing abrasive and social lubricant to get the job done.

If you are going to go the DIY route, emery board might be better and less risky and you can control the amount of material that is removed over time. Start with that, even on the aluminum and work up to a metal file if needed.

You'll want a fine emery board to polish things either way, but do try to get a scrap case to test on before you start (or at least get a quote to replace the part should you like the modified case worse than the new edge.)

Comment: All good ideas, but I'm really looking for someone who has already gambled with his own precious hardware.

Comment: I can say from personal experience to _not_ use a blade on the polycarbonate mac. It's possible to have success but very easy to cut too deeply. Emery boards work well if you just want to blunt the edge. We didn't try to polish that mac and just let time and general use polish it. Lots of people have used a dremel on the Aluminum macs and documented it online. You can see most are not uniform hence my warning to get a pro to help there. It really depends on how picky you are (and how skilled your hands). Some people go into fits if their mac has a scratch - others don't care about cosmetics.

Comment: Someone who cuts too deeply needs to flip the blade so that the sharp side is trailing. This way a thin layer is shaved at each swipe.

Answer (score 2):

The edges are sharp but they are also brittle. I never wore watches or bracelets but the angle of my aluminum MacBook Pro of 2011 was threadbare (like saw teeth).

I used an old sticker (brand Venilia) of my grandmother who used to pad the inside of cupboards (strange old French modes!).

[image: Customized adhesive vinyl]

Price : $ 0! Risk: no! The material is soft to the touch, MacBook's closes well and I purposely hide the diode ("Sleep indicator light"), which for me was too bright at night!

[image: Customized adhesive vinyl]]

Design inspiration come from this Latvian handywoman from Etsy :
www.etsy.com/listing/259580847/soot-sprite-macbook-decal-vinyl-laptop

(It's my first post, not enough reputation to give you more pictures, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

I used a small file to *carefully* round the sharp edge that was digging into my palms. It worked really well but left some scratch marks from the file.

I finished cleaning it up with some light sandpaper.

If you do this, be very careful to ensure no aluminum dust gets inside the keys, speakers, or case. That would not be good.